# How to run Java Selenium tests on Chrome with third party cookies blocked?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

I have a goal to change some java selenium tests to run chrome with third party cookies blocked. Is there a way to do this?

Is there a known working example of how to do this? Examples I see online suggest using "profile.default_content_settings.cookies" and setting the value to a 2 or maybe 3? I also saw some older techniques that also don't work.

Resources I found:

- [Run selenium with cookies turned off (SmartBear)](https://support.smartbear.com/crossbrowsertesting/docs/automated-testing/frameworks/selenium/about/run-selenium-with-cookies-turned-off.html)
- [Reddit question - someone else having an issue getting it to work.](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/15fc4ge/query_how_to_allow_all_cookies_on_chrome_using/)

Comment: I would try with options.addArguments("--test-third-party-cookie-phaseout");

Comment: OR, try using a pref...  HashMap<String, Object> prefs; prefs.put("profile.block_third_party_cookies", true); options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

Comment: @pcalkins - thank you! The first one you posted worked it seems. The Chrome UI still says cookies are only blocked in incognito mode in my privacy setting (which is confusing!), but when I check on https://www.whatismybrowser.com/ , it reports that only the 3rd party cookies are blocked. I also found docs on this on google: https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/privacy-sandbox/third-party-cookie-phase-out/

problem solved

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments above (thank you @pcalkins), you need to use options.addArguments("--test-third-party-cookie-phaseout")

The Chrome UI still says cookies are only blocked in incognito mode in my privacy setting (which is confusing!), but when I check on whatismybrowser.com , it reports that only the 3rd party cookies are blocked. I also found docs on this on google: [Third party cookie phase out](https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/privacy-sandbox/third-party-cookie-phase-out/).